# How do I use crontab on my Mac to upload a specific file via ftp once per hour?

Tags: macos, ftp, cron

I have a specific file on my Mac that I would like to be uploaded to my webspace via ftp once per hour. I'd like for it to happen automatically in the background with no indication that it's being uploaded. I read something about crontab, but haven't been able to figure out how to use it. Could someone take a second to explain it to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you've tried, so I'm going to guess you haven't. Our friends at google have this amazing thing called a search engine. I searched on "mac crontab" and got about 1,000,000 hits.

One of the first was [Cronnix](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7486/cronnix). It's GUI so you may not even have to RTM.

Somewhat less sarcastically ...

Cron is pretty basic. It runs every minute and sees if anything needs to be done. There are user-specific crontabs, and system crontabs, the only difference being that system crontabs specify the user the command is to be run as. The following user crontab:

```
#min    hour    mday    month   wday    command
25      2,14     *       *       *      sh path/to/getmybackup.sh
```

causes the backup script to be run everyday (the `*`s) at 0225 and 1425 (local). There are a lot of shortcut notations that you can use, so I really do recommend reading the [cron man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/crontab.1.html) and the [crontab (5) man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/crontab). I suspect that cronnix makes some of this somewhat less cryptic.

Comment: I do, of course, know how to use a search engine. I guess what I'm asking for is an explanation of how it works.